# Are white spaces and blank lines in http response affect the speed of downloading the page?

Tags: html, http, networking

I found by `wget some_url` that it has so many white spaces and blank lines like

```
               <span class="meta">

                            someValue


            </span>
```

And the whole document downloaded by `wget` is in good layout as we can see in Chrome dev tools,Does the document has so many white spaces and blank lines (or tabs) and they're downloaded as well as the main content.
e.g
if the document(also, download by wget or curl)  is:

```
<div class="   someclass">

   somevalue

  </div>
```

there're 5 spaces(3 before `someclass` , 2 before `</div>`) and 2 blank lines wrapping `somevalue`
Was it downloaded in tighten form like:
`<div class="someclass">somevalue</div>`
if not,I'm shock by the fact that some many bandwidth is wasted by these mostly useless information,Are the just the wasted(except they're for layout purpose)?

Comment: Note: White space is less of an issue for websites that minify or obfuscate the code, and for web servers that allow the code to be compressed while in transit (plus, any group of consecutive identical characters is more-compressible than a group of mixed characters).

Answer (score 4):

It is my understanding that whitespace takes up just as much as a character- So technically yes, it's "a waste". However, generally speaking, it is something that you would not ever notice as there are many other things that hinder load time. if You were loading an incredibly large page with a high percentage of whitespace on an incredibly slow network, you might be able to notice.

Generally it is better to think not about how it affects performance (because it doesn't) and think more about whether it makes your code readable. When writing something you need to revisit or show to others, whitespace is very important. When obscuring code so people won't mess with it, getting rid of whitespace can go a long way.

Comment: Plus, if the HTML is compressed while in transit (as is the case for many websites), a long series of blank spaces (or tabs, or new lines) will compress much better than the same number of mixed alphanumeric characters would. So the impact is less.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. At what point does this occur?

Comment: I would argue that the readability of any markup or code being served to the client is a non-issue as well. Since the code the client sees is not necessarily the code the developer writes, it does not matter how readable any markup or code being received from the server is. In such cases, reducing file size is much more important, hence the minification of JS and CSS assets.

Comment: @PrimitiveType: If the HTML is compressed, it happens invisibly behind the scenes. The web server compresses it before sending it, and the browser decompresses it before starting to parse it. This happens if the web server is configured to compress files, and the browser identifies itself as having support for compression. At least, that's as far as I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a compression algorithm for the webserver to use with the Content-Encoding header. For example, **gzip**: http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

However, the webserver doesn't *have to* do it. It's like you're strongly hinting for the webserver to compress your traffic.

Comment: I believe the web server can also be configured to prefer compressing files, but it still depends on the browser identifying in the HTTP request that it supports compression.

Comment: Yup. But in 2013 we can be pretty assured that modern browsers will all by default compress.